# Why does my Tkinter toplevel freeze after a while?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have stopwatch running on both my main window and my top level. The watch starts as soon as the program is launched and is stopped by closing the program. The toplevel is launched by using a button. The toplevel is supposed to display a copy of the stopwatch. But, when I keep the toplevel open for over an hour, it freezes. The main window runs fine. The toplevel works fine for another hour or so when I manually close and reopen it. Does anyone know what could be the problem? I'm running the code on Windows OS.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import datetime
import time
import tkinter as tk

time_elapse_flag = False
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
diff = 0

def time_elapse():
    global time_elapse_flag
    global diff

    if(not time_elapse_flag):      
            time_elapse_flag = True
            time_elapse_count = tk.Label(window, text='', relief='sunken', bg='white', font='Helvetica 16 bold')
            time_elapse_count.place(x=10, y=150, width=200, height=50)
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

            time_elapse_label = tk.Label(window, text='Recording data since:', font='Helvetica 12 bold')
            time_elapse_label.place(x=10, y=120, width=200, height=30)

            def update_time():
                global start_time
                global diff
                current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
                diff = current_time - start_time
                time_elapse_count.config(text=diff)
                time_elapse_label.after(1000,update_time)

            update_time()

    else:
        time_elapse_flag = False
        time_elapse_count = tk.Label(window, text='')
        time_elapse_count.place(x=10, y=150, width=200, height=50)

        time_elapse_label = tk.Label(window, text='')
        time_elapse_label.place(x=10, y=120, width=200, height=30)

def Param_Window():   
    global time_elapse_flag
    global diff

    pw = tk.Toplevel()
    pw.geometry('1200x550') 

    def update_values():
        global diff

        if(time_elapse_flag):
                time_elapse_label = tk.Label(pw, text='Recording data since:', font='Helvetica 20 bold')
                time_elapse_count = tk.Label(pw, text=diff, relief='sunken', bg='white', font='Helvetica 16 bold')
                time_elapse_label.place(x=640, y=350, width=300, height=50)
                time_elapse_count.place(x=640, y=400, width=200, height=50)
        else:
                time_elapse_label = tk.Label(pw, text='')
                time_elapse_count = tk.Label(pw, text='')
                time_elapse_label.place(x=640, y=350, width=300, height=50)
                time_elapse_count.place(x=640, y=400, width=200, height=50)

        pw.after(800,update_values)

    update_values()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('550x250')

    disp_param_button = tk.Button(window, text='Display Parameters', command=Param_Window, bg='sky blue', font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, state='normal', relief='raised')
    disp_param_button.place(x=300, y=150)
    print('Automatically starting in')

    for cd in range(5):
        print(5-cd)
        time.sleep(1)

    time_elapse()

    window.mainloop( )
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you posted so far. But I assume it's not the whole thing, since there aren't any imports, and you never define `fio2_flag` and a number of other variables. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Oh my bad. Those flags have no effect. Let me remove it. The whole code is way too long and unnecessary. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Don't use `sleep()` in tkinter. Instead use `after()` sleep will freeze the mainloop. You also have an indention problem in your code.

Comment: I have intentionally used sleep to prevent the main window from popping up immediately. Forgive my indentation. It is a result of the copy paste.I'll correct that. I thought I got them all

Comment: You still should not use sleep. You can simply use after and set a counter and then open the main window after the counter completes.

Comment: What do you mean by the toplevel "freezing"? Do you mean you don't see the time changing? What have you done to debug this? Have you added some logging statements to verify that the code which updates the screen is being called?

Comment: The indentation can't simply be "forgiven" : identation is what defines the program structure in Python, and the above snippet is simply unreadable. (is `update_values()` calling itself at the end? ).

Just paste your code as is here and use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: @BryanOakley the toplevel just doesn't respond. I can click on the buttons but it doesn't do anything. The values in the textboxes don't get updated

Comment: @Shawn Bryan's answer is correct but please fix your indention as well. Each new level of indention is 4 spaces. Multiple sections of your code are 8 spaces.

Comment: @jsbueno Again I apologize. I understand it can't be 'forgiven'. I have 8 other threads running in the background that has nothing to do with the tkinter. I didn't want to include 2 pages of irrelevant code. I used notepad to copy paste the relevent code and that messed up the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating two new label widgets every 800 milliseconds in `Param_Window`. When you run for an hour, that means you will have created 4,500 label widgets. At some point you're going to hit a hard limit, because you can't create an infinite number of widgets.

You need to restructure your code so that you create the labels once and then reconfigure them instead of creating new widgets on every iteration.

Comment: That might be it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bryan's answer you should also move the code for sleep to be outside of the tk instance and fix your indention.

Here is a corrected version of your code that will fix all the problems I can see.

1. Indention fix
2. Sleep moved outside of tk instance (not related to your main problem but is wrong just the same)
3. changed the `Param_Window` function to update labels instead of recreating them ever 0.8 seconds.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
import time

time_elapse_flag = False
start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

def time_elapse():
    global time_elapse_flag
    global diff

    if(not time_elapse_flag):      
        time_elapse_flag = True
        time_elapse_count = tk.Label(window, text='', relief='sunken', bg='white', font='Helvetica 16 bold')
        time_elapse_count.place(x=10, y=150, width=200, height=50)
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)

        time_elapse_label = tk.Label(window, text='Recording data since:', font='Helvetica 12 bold')
        time_elapse_label.place(x=10, y=120, width=200, height=30)

        def update_time():
            global start_time
            global diff
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
            diff = current_time - start_time
            time_elapse_count.config(text=diff)
            time_elapse_label.after(1000, update_time)

        update_time()

    else:
        time_elapse_flag = False
        time_elapse_count = tk.Label(window, text='')
        time_elapse_count.place(x=10, y=150, width=200, height=50)

        time_elapse_label = tk.Label(window, text='')
        time_elapse_label.place(x=10, y=120, width=200, height=30)


def Param_Window():   
    global time_elapse_flag
    global diff

    pw = tk.Toplevel()
    pw.geometry('1200x550') 
    time_elapse_label = tk.Label(pw, text='Recording data since:', font='Helvetica 20 bold')
    time_elapse_count = tk.Label(pw, text=diff, relief='sunken', bg='white', font='Helvetica 16 bold')
    time_elapse_label.place(x=640, y=350, width=300, height=50)
    time_elapse_count.place(x=640, y=400, width=200, height=50)

    def update_values():
        global diff

        if(time_elapse_flag):
            time_elapse_label.config(text='Recording data since:')
            time_elapse_count.config(text=diff)

        else:
            time_elapse_label.config(text='')
            time_elapse_count.config(text='')

        pw.after(800, update_values)

        update_values()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print('Automatically starting in')

    for cd in range(5):
        print(5-cd)
        time.sleep(1)

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('550x250')

    disp_param_button = tk.Button(window, text='Display Parameters', command=Param_Window, bg='sky blue', font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, state='normal', relief='raised')
    disp_param_button.place(x=300, y=150)

    time_elapse()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: That sleep only affects the program the first five seconds after the program starts. It has nothing to do with what happens an hour later. While the advice is good, it's a bit irrelevant to the question. And in fact, maybe this is one of the few times when sleep is ok -- the user wants to delay startup and display a countdown on stdout, and this is certainly one way to do it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I know its not related to the main problem of the question but using sleep inside of tkinter can cause problems so I added it as a "keep it in mind" bit to let the OP know that they should not use sleep in tkinter at all. Oh and congratz on 200k Bryan! I have been watching your rep grow over the past year. You certainly do a lot on here :D.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you and congratulations. A lot of your answers have helped me learn python. Appreciate your contribution

Comment: @Mike-SMT thank you. I guess it is good practice to avoid using sleep in tkinter even when it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Shawn It is. I know in this particular case it is not hurting you but most of the time using sleep inside of the tk instance results in freezing that causes many problems by blocking the mainloop. Bryan is correct as always. It is not actually all that big a deal in this case. I added it as more of a future reference for other code you may write.